# Unexpected result with sort -u

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

If I run this sort:

```
printf "Will be second line post-sort\nWill be first line post-sort" \
  | sort -k1,1
```

I get as output:

```
Will be first line post-sort  
Will be second line post-sort
```

as expected (key fields are the same but the sort uses last-resort comparison). However if I add the -u option:

```
printf "Will be second line post-sort\nWill be first line post-sort" \
  | sort -k1,1 -u
```

I get as ouput:

```
Will be second line post-sort
```

instead of the expected:

```
Will be first line post-sort
```

Why does sort -u return first line of the pre-sorted data rather than the first line of the post-sorted data in this case?

BTW I can get the desired behavior by sorting (without the -u) first:

```
printf "Will be second line post-sort\nWill be first line post-sort" \
  | sort -k1,1 | sort -k1,1 -u
```

Comment: This is an implementation artifact. POSIX [provides no guarantees](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) as to which of multiple lines with identical keys will be chosen. You can not rely on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can depend on precisely which of the lines will be in the output. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) says:

> `-u`
>       **Unique**: suppress all but one in each set of lines having equal keys.

It doesn't say which of the lines having equal keys will be in the output, just that there will only be one of them. So if you want a specific one, you should use some other tool like `awk`

Comment: I took a peek at the source code for sort (I should have done this to start with)  and it looks like the elimination of duplicates occurs during the sort rather than before. Nonetheless, you are absolutely correct, there is no guarantee which line among lines with equal keys will get output. My mental model of the sort -u was that it was implemented to behave similar to sort|uniq. Glad to know about this subtle difference before I ran into problems with it!